# Classification vs DTW after clustering the data

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, unsupervised-learning

My task is to predict the in which state the test instance is in. My train set has M instances time series each instance having different duration. Each instance has 5 states in train data (s1, s2, s3, s4, s5). All the states occur in the same order for each instance. In my test data, not all the instances have all the 5 states. My goal is to predict in which state a particular instance is in. The class labels are not given. I have performed hierarchical clustering to segment each train instance. While prediction, I used fast DTW to find similarity of a particular test instance with all M train instances. I choose the one with minimum distance. I used this train model to find in the current state of the test instance.

But I'm not sure how accurate this would be. I could apply classifier with cluster numbers as labels but I want to have more robust approach as my data is high dimensional. Are there any performance metrics to consider while performing DTW? Using classification restricts me as my test set does not have all the states information and I should limit my data to only train set. Clearly, might fail in predicting the current state.

Comment: So you are doing "something", but have no idea if it is good? Then you probably lost track of what you were trying to do in the first place.